# How to concatenate React component and a string?

Tags: webpack, reactjs, webpack-2, react-bootstrap

I want to do the following in a `title` prop:

```js
<Tab title={<Glyphicon glyph="time" /> Real-Time}></Tab>
```

But it doesn't work. I get `Unexpected token, expected }`. So a `string` cannot follow a React component.

How to make it work without arrays, functions, creating new components, etc. Does React has means to do it in one line, like in my example?

Answer (score 5):

My solution is with array:

```
<Tab title={[<Glyphicon glyph="briefcase" />, "Briefcase"]}>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, however I had to add keys to avoid the "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." warning. For anyone else with the same issue, I added a span tag for the string part: setError([<span key="msg">This email address is already signed up for an account! Please sign in </span>, <Link key="link" to="/signup">here</Link>]);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this. Then again, this assumes title can accept a component. In most cases, title usually just accepts a string. I'd check to see the Prop types or flowtype of the `Tab` component.

```
_renderTitle () {
  return (
   <Glyphicon glyph='time' />
  )
}

render () {
  return (
    <Tab title={this._renderTitle} />
  )
}
```